# Number of available threads in Julia?

Tags: multithreading, julia

In Julia is it still the case that the number of threads that can be created is limited by the number of physically available cores? Or has Julia lang changed since March so that the number of threads is limited to the number of logical cores?

Comment: I believe it was previously limited to the number logical cores (*not* physical cores), but now that restriction is gone.

Answer (score 6):

The restriction was lifted with [PR #36778](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/36778), so in Julia master (what in a few months will become v1.6) you can start Julia with as many threads as you want:

```
% julia-master --threads 20 -q
julia> using Base.Threads

julia> nthreads()
20
```

You can use `--threads auto` (or `-t auto`) to start Julia with the number of threads available on the system:

```
% julia-master --threads auto -q                
julia> using Base.Threads

julia> nthreads()
8
```

Comment: Can you change the number of threads after you open a Julia repl, or do I have to close my repl and reopen a new one?

Comment: At the moment, the number of threads used by Julia can only be set at startup time, either with the `JULIA_NUM_THREADS` environment variable or the `--threads`/`-t` flag.